# Throttling in OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We have a registered AAD application marked as multi-tenant. We are using this App ID to generate a Token for Microsoft Graph.

- The first user is a Global Admin in the Tenant where the app is registered.
- The second user is part of another Tenant.

When the second user tried to use Microsoft Graph to get information from OneDrive, we sometimes get an `HTTP 429 activityLimitReached` error.

We read the guide about [throttling](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/throttling) and it says to repeat the request after the `Retry-After` value from the response header. But in our case there is no `Retry-After` field in the response.

We received this error by executing one request per day. Also, after receiving the `429`, we can retry and get a successful result (after several attempts). This error appears only in the OneDrive, the other services are OK.

What can we do to avoid `429` error? How can we check the current limit or increase it?

Example of request

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/:userId/drives
```

Example of response

```
HTTP/1.1 429 
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 377d2cdf-7be3-4286-819a-46060330365f
client-request-id: 377d2cdf-7be3-4286-819a-46060330365f
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceA","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_13","ADSiteName":"AMS"}}
Duration: 170.5668
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Wed, 23 May 2018 11:39:08 GMT

{
  "error": {
    "code": "activityLimitReached",
    "message": "The request has been throttled",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "377d2cdf-7be3-4286-819a-46060330365f",
      "date": "2018-05-23T11:39:09"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the Client Credentials or Authentication Code OAuth flow?

Comment: We use this approach https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

Comment: How many calls is your app making into the tenant (i.e. across all users)?

Answer (score 1):

> What can we do to avoid 429 error? How can we check the current limit or increase it?

To avoid the 429 error, we must control our request, don't do too many request within limited time. The limit issue is known issue we canot increase it now.

> Setting and publishing exact throttling limits sounds very straightforward, but in fact, it's not the best way to go. We continually monitor resource usage on SharePoint Online. Depending on usage, we fine-tune thresholds so users can consume the maximum number of resources without degrading the reliability and performance of SharePoint Online.

Above reference is from MS documentation about throttling and OneDrive for Business/SharePoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online

I would suggest going to [UserVoice for Graph](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and suggest an improvement (or upvote an existing one). The feedback helps Product Group prioritize future work based on the interest in those suggested improvements. But based on the above official docs, **the best solution is still to contorl our request but not the feature request**.

Comment: We tried it with curl. Our application did not execute any requests for 24 hours. After a pause, we performed one request using curl and got an `HTTP 429 activityLimitReached` error (The `Retry-After` header was not presented in the response).

What type of throttling can be on a single request per day?

Comment: Not sure the throttling for OneDrive. Based on my usage experience of Azure Management API, the throttling can be 10000/month or such value. So the value for each day is very low. We can contact the MS support to increase the throttling for paying more. Didn't execute any requests is due to have beyond the limit of the period.

Comment: this behaviour sounds like a bug, not a known issue. one request a day can't be hitting any throttling limits.

Comment: Because Ivan maybe have send too many request before, so azure limit his request during a peroid of time. Within this peroid of time, one request a day hitting throtting is normal, due to it have not  been lifted throtting  limit

Comment: Have you tried the same scenario using the onedrive apis directly. Presumably that will tell you if it is a onedrive issue or microsoftgraph issue?

Comment: It all looks like a bug. 
1) There is no retry-after header;
2) After the first error, we perform several more requests and get a successful result;
3) If the limit were for a month then we would not have a successful result (after several attempts);
4) The error appears only when we call OneDrive. We also use the same approach to receive Outlook but everything is fine (The number of requests even exceeds the number of requests for a OneDrive).

Comment: I am not sure if it is bug now, still need to more test, but you can submit it on the Github issue first. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues. Although the PG member maybe will check StackOverflow too.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have much experience with the onedrive-api but I have certainly experienced throttling when using the onenote-api.
 This post on how [onenote throttles](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2016/01/12/onenote-api-throttling-and-how-to-avoid-it/) may be more useful than the generic microsoft graph link in your question.
 In particular, long calls against the api will result in throttling occurring much sooner than more targetted calls (and you need to let calls finish before issuing new calls, be very careful with queueing multiple curl requests).
 Once you have been throttled trying the same call over and over will likely increase the length of time throttling occurs (I haven't seen as full day but I have seen several hours before).
I presume (but am not sure) that all microsoftgraph-api calls will internally count towards resource limits, but if you direct onedrive calls against the onedrive-api this will not count against the microsoft-graph limits and may allow the requests you need without throttling.
I would definitely recommend getting a second access token for the direct onedrive api (you can use the same refresh token) and try this approach.

```
GET https://www.onedrive.com/v1.0/users/:userId/drives
```

If it is one user in particular that has issues maybe they have exceeded their tenant resources?

Comment: I hit my first `Too Many Requests (status code 429)` today. There is a GitHub issue requesting more information on the limits: [Rate Limiting Policy Documentation Improvements](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/853)